# Awesomium Web Browser - How WebCore.Shutdown & WebCore.Initialize Again

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, awesomium, .net-4.6.1

I am using [Awesomium](http://www.awesomium.com/) as a web browser control in my winform application.
In a button's click event i want to Shutdown & ReInitialize [WebCore](http://docs.awesomium.net/html/T_Awesomium_Core_WebCore.htm).
How can i do this job?
I wrote these codes, but i got the error below :

**Codes :**

```
webBrowser_main.Dispose(); <------> I want to remove this previous awesomium control & recreate it again with same ID
WebCore.Shutdown();

await dl(5000, 7000);

WebConfig config = new WebConfig() { UserAgent = "blablabla", LogLevel = LogLevel.None };
WebCore.Initialize(config); <------> I HAVE ERROR HERE
WebCore.Initialized += WebCoreInitialzed;
WebCore.Download += WebCoreDownload;

WebControl browser = new WebControl();
browser.Name = "webBrowser_main";
browser.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.GreenYellow;
browser.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 29);
browser.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(960, 565);
browser.TabIndex = 52;
browser.ViewType = Awesomium.Core.WebViewType.Offscreen;
browser.ShowJavascriptDialog += new Awesomium.Core.JavascriptDialogEventHandler(webBrowser_main_ShowJavascriptDialog);
browser.TargetURLChanged += new Awesomium.Core.UrlEventHandler(webBrowser_main_TargetURLChanged);
browser.ShowCreatedWebView += new Awesomium.Core.ShowCreatedWebViewEventHandler(webBrowser_main_ShowCreatedWebView);
browser.DocumentReady += new Awesomium.Core.DocumentReadyEventHandler(webBrowser_main_DocumentReady);
browser.LoadingFrame += new Awesomium.Core.LoadingFrameEventHandler(webBrowser_main_LoadingFrame);
browser.LoadingFrameComplete += new Awesomium.Core.FrameEventHandler(webBrowser_main_LoadingFrameComplete);
browser.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(webBrowser_main_MouseMove);
browser.Source = new System.Uri("https://www.google.com", System.UriKind.Absolute);
browser.TabIndex = 0;
this.Controls.Add(browser);
```

**And here is the error :**

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   Awesomium.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: You are attempting to re-initialize the
>   WebCore. The WebCore must only be initialized once per process and
>   must be shut down only when the process exits.

Comment: Error message seems to be pretty clear about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now Chromium does not support "re-initialization" after Shutdown() method was called. So, libraries based on it (Awesomium, CEF etc) do not support such functionality as well.

Depending on why do you need this functionality, you can try something else (e.g. clear cache, cookies).

Comment: Which library is better than Awesomium?

Comment: It really depends on your needs. Awesomium is awesome, but it is not free for commercial development.
Sometime it is easier to use standard WebBrowser component.